# How do I reverse the column values and leave the column headers as they are

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

suppose I have a dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

Which looks like this

```
   A  B  C  D   E
0  1  2  3  4   5
1  6  7  8  9  10
```

How do I reverse the order of the column values but leave the column headers as A, B, C, D, E?

I want it to look like

```
    A  B  C  D  E
0   5  4  3  2  1
1  10  9  8  7  6
```

I've tried sorting the column index `df.sort_index(1, ascending=False)` but that changes the column heads (obviously) and also, I don't know if my columns start off in a sorted way anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can just reverse your columns:

```
df.columns = reversed(df.columns)
df.sortlevel(axis=1)

#   A   B   C   D   E
#0  5   4   3   2   1
#1  10  9   8   7   6
```

Comment: This answer is great!  To get in the same order as before, I'd `df.reindex_axis(reversed(df.columns))` or something similar.

Comment: @piRSquared Yeah, `reindex_axis` is probably a better solution here.

Answer (score 3):

***method 1***
**reconstruct**

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values[:, ::-1], df.index, df.columns)
```

***method 2***
**assign values**

```
df[:] = df.values[:, ::-1]
df
```

***both give***
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also, using [`np.fliplr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) which flips the values along the horizontal direction:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.fliplr(df.values), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

[image]